# Sending a JSON string to a php file without using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

This question may be very stupid, but i'm a beginner in web development and I would like to know if there is a way to send JSON string to a php file without using AJAX?

I had a Exam question like this : "Submit the JSON object to the PHP file. In the PHP file you must convert the JSON string into a PHP object."

How this would be possible without AJAX?

Thank you

Comment: json($data); $data containing serialized objects for instance :)

Comment: Every method that allows you to send data, e.g. `curl`

Comment: You can put the JSON string in a hidden form input, and then submit the form normally instead of using AJAX.

Comment: Can you help me with some topic to search on google to understand better what you have just said? @KA_lin

Comment: You can use CURL too...

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your reply, but they ask us to send it from the javascript file and not directly from the form

Comment: $data being an array of strings(serialized arrays) then it is json- encoded http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php

Comment: Then AJAX is the only way. AJAX is the name of sending data from Javascript to the server.

Comment: @RobertRozas How would you use cURL from Javascript?

Comment: So, did you include the entire exam question? Because what you've included doesn't say not to use AJAX and it sounds like that's what you should use.

Comment: @JPod in the exam they dont say what method to use. But the problem is in the last question they have something similar in which they specifically say we must use AJAX

Comment: So that is why im wondering if there is a way to do this without AJAX

Comment: @Barmar...you are right, i didn't read the JS part of the question....oooh wait, that part doesn't exist!!!

Comment: where does it say don't use AJAX?

Comment: @charlietfl He's saying that it's implied, because otherwise this would be the same as the later question that specifically says to use AJAX. So now I wonder where it says not to use `form.submit()`. That's Javascript, but it uses normal form submission.

Comment: @Barmar I think you are right. making the form.submit() would be the way to do it. Thank you for your time

Comment: if you can't use a form, and you cant use ajax, you could use window.location or an iframe, or an image, or anything else that retrieves data from the server.

Comment: @beckinho Since the exam directions for this question are vague at best, I would either contact the teacher for clarification, if possible, or just do it in AJAX if that's not possible.

Comment: @JPod the problem is they just gave us last year exam to practice and I didnt have any chance to ask the lecturer about how you could do this question. Im writing my exam tomorrow so I thought maybe I could get some help here.

Answer (score 2):

in html page:

```
<a href="http://phpfile.php?jsonstring=%7B%22a%22%3A1%7D">send, receive and convert</a>
```

in phpfile.php:

```
$json = json_decode($_REQUEST['jsonstring']);
var_dump($json);
```

result is:

```
$json = ["a" => 1]
```